# It is not possible to use PKZIP encryption on a non-seekable input stream

Tags: c#, zip

I use DotNetZip.

I get error

> It is not possible to use PKZIP encryption on a non-seekable input
>   stream

what to do

```
var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password = "123456!";
    var outputStreamFile = new MemoryStream();
    var userId = m_userRepository.GetuserByLogin(this.User.Identity.Name).UserId;

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStreamFile))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(m_kamikaze2Repository.GetGameById(gameId, userId).Result);

    }
    zip.AddEntry("result_" + gameId, outputStreamFile);
    zip.Save(outputStream);//error

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `outpuStreamFile` is closed when you add it to the `ZipFile`. `StreamWriter.Dispose` will dispose the stream so just move the `using` statement to ensure that `outputStreamFile` is available when you call `zip.Save`.

Also, before adding `outputStreamFile` to the `ZipFile` you need to rewind it.

```
using (var outputStreamFile = new MemoryStream()) {
  var userId = m_userRepository.GetuserByLogin(this.User.Identity.Name).UserId;
  var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStreamFile);
  streamWriter.WriteLine(m_kamikaze2Repository.GetGameById(gameId, userId).Result);
  outputStreamFile.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  zip.AddEntry("result_" + gameId, outputStreamFile);     
  zip.Save(outputStream);
}
```

Comment: error is gone, but the zip is empty, it does not even show it to supposedly saved

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.Password = "123456!";

    zip.AddEntry("result_" + gameId, "Some content");
    zip.Save(outputStream);

    byte[] zipFile = outputStream.ToArray();
    // TODO: do something with the zip
}
```